# Why consider this homology relation on vector fields?

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, vector-fields, spin-geometry

I am studying Turaev's work on torsions of manifolds, specifically the paper Euler Structures, Nonsingular Vector Fields, and Torsions of Reidemeister Type.  (I cannot find an open-access version of that to link to but see the letter [Torsion Invariants of Spin-c-Structures on 3-Manifolds](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1997/0004/0005/MRL-1997-0004-0005-a006.pdf), specifically Section 1.3 ).

He defines a *smooth Euler structure* on a closed, oriented manifold to be a homology class $[u]$ of a non-singular vector field $u$ on $M$ (say $\dim M =m \ge 2$).

> Two non-singular vector fields $u$ and $v$ are said to be homologous if for some closed $m$-dimensional ball $D \subset M$ the restrictions of $u$ and $v$ to $M \setminus \text{int}(D)$ are homotopic in the class of non-singular vector fields.

My question is, Why is this an interesting homology relation for non-singular vector fields?  In particular, why do we take out the ball $D$ before searching for a homotopy?  What would go wrong if we tried to look for homotopies of $u$ and $v$ on all of $M$, instead of just $M\setminus D$?

Turaev cites V. G. Boltyanskii, Homotopy Classification of Vector Fields, but I haven't been able to find this paper (and suspect that it is in Russian, which I can't read).  Can anyone recommend a reference for more on this homology relation on vector fields?